# VBA: If range equals any of the listbox selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro (Courtesy of another questions i posted on here) which works perfectly. It searched through data and rearranged it to my needs. It also only outputted information that matched a criteria given (E.g. A cell equals the specified string).

However, now i have added a list box in where the user can select multiple criteria. But i am not sure how i can use VBA to search through the data and only output the data which matches ANY of the list box selections. As shown in the image, if the user selects CONACC and CONPEND, the code should search through the data and then output the values where the cell equals either CONACC or CONPEND.

Any ideas?

[Userform Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIEYW.png)

```
'type to manage data we use from each row
Type dataRow
    notif As Variant
    variable As Variant
    sht As Variant
    zone As Variant
End Type
Sub DoPivot()
    Const SEP As String = "<>"
    Dim rngData As Range, data, r As Long
    Dim colDict As Object, rowDict As Object, comboDict As Object
    Dim rd As dataRow, rngOutput As Range, col As Long, rw As Long, k
    Dim k2, arr, dictCounts As Object
    Dim wsOut As Worksheet, num As Long
    Dim DataWS, OutputtedWS As Worksheet
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim DataWb, OutputtedWb As Workbook
    Dim DataFileName, DataSheetName, DataSheetFilter As String

    Set colDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rowDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set comboDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dictCounts = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    DataFileName = DataFilter.FileLocationTextbox.Value
    DataSheetName = DataFilter.SheetNameTextBox.Value

    Set OutputtedWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataWb = Workbooks.Open(DataFileName)

    Set DataWS = DataWb.Sheets(DataSheetName)
    Set OutputtedWS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

    Dim DataWsLastCol As Long, DataWsLastColLet As String
    Dim DataWsLastRow As Long

    DataWsLastCol = DataWS.Cells(1, DataWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    DataWsLastColLet = Split(Cells(1, DataWsLastCol).Address, "$")(1)
    DataWsLastRow = DataWS.Range("A:" & DataWsLastColLet).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    data = DataWS.Range("A2:" & DataWsLastColLet & DataWsLastRow).Value 'source data

    Set rngOutput = OutputtedWS.Range("A1")    'top-left cell for output
    Set wsOut = rngOutput.Parent

    rngOutput.Resize(5000, 5000).ClearContents

    rngOutput.Resize(1, 6).Value = Array("Sheet", "Zone", "Feature Code", "Feature Description", "-TEN OGV KH73126 tolerance", "-TEN OGV KH73126 tolerance")
    OutputtedWS.Cells(2, 5) = "Nominal"
    OutputtedWS.Cells(2, 6) = "Tolerance"

    Set notif = DataWS.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Notification", lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set variable = DataWS.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Extent Var.", lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set sht = DataWS.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Sheet", lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set zone = DataWS.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Zone", lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set CodeGroup = DataWS.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Code group", lookat:=xlWhole)

     notifcol = notif.Column
     variablecol = variable.Column
     shtcol = sht.Column
     zonecol = zone.Column
     CodeGroupCol = CodeGroup.Column

    col = rngOutput.Column + 6 'start for notification# headers
    rw = rngOutput.Row + 2

    'first pass - assess data variables
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(r, CodeGroupCol) = [[[[[[THIS IS WHERE THE SELECTION WOULD GO]]]]]] Then
            rd = rowData(data, r, notifcol, variablecol, shtcol, zonecol)
            k = Join(Array(rd.sht, rd.zone, rd.notif), SEP) 'tracking how many unique combinations of these
            comboDict(k) = comboDict(k) + 1 'increment count
            'manage column header positions for unique notification numbers
            If Not colDict.exists(rd.notif) Then
                colDict.Add rd.notif, col 'store the column
                rngOutput.EntireRow.Cells(1, col).Value = rd.notif 'add the header
                col = col + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    'figure out # of rows for each sheet-Zone pair
    For Each k In comboDict.keys
        arr = Split(k, SEP)
        k2 = Join(Array(arr(0), arr(1)), SEP) 'sheet<>zone
        'is this more rows than any previous same k2 value?
        dictCounts(k2) = Application.Max(dictCounts(k2), comboDict(k))
    Next k

    'create the row headers
    For Each k In dictCounts.keys
        num = dictCounts(k)
        rowDict(k) = rw         'record start row for each sheet<>zone combo
        wsOut.Cells(rw, rngOutput.Column).Resize(num, 2).Value = Split(k, SEP)
        dictCounts(k) = 0 'reset so we can track while adding data
        rowDict(k) = rw
        rw = rw + num
    Next k

    'last pass - populate the data based on the dictionaries
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(r, CodeGroupCol) = [[[[[[THIS IS WHERE THE SELECTION WOULD GO]]]]]] Then
            rd = rowData(data, r, notifcol, variablecol, shtcol, zonecol)
            k = Join(Array(rd.sht, rd.zone, rd.notif), SEP) '3-field combo
            k2 = Join(Array(rd.sht, rd.zone), SEP)          'row key

            wsOut.Cells(rowDict(k2) + (dictCounts(k)), _
                        colDict(rd.notif)).Value = rd.variable

            dictCounts(k) = dictCounts(k) + 1               'increment this unique combo
        End If
    Next r

End Sub

'populate a Type instance for a given row
Function rowData(data, r As Long, notficationcol, variablecol, sheetcol, zonecol) As dataRow
    Dim rv As dataRow
    rv.notif = IfEmpty(data(r, notficationcol))
    rv.variable = IfEmpty(data(r, variablecol))
    rv.sht = IfEmpty(data(r, sheetcol))
    rv.zone = IfEmpty(data(r, zonecol))
    rowData = rv
End Function

'substitute EMPTY for zero-length value
Function IfEmpty(v)
    IfEmpty = IIf(Len(v) = 0, "EMPTY", v)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another dictionary

```vb
    Dim i As Integer, dictFilter As Object
    Set dictFilter = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With DataFilter.ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
           If .Selected(i) = True Then
               dictFilter.Add .List(i), 1
           End If
        Next
    End With


    If dictFilter.exists(data(r, CodeGroupCol)) Then
       '
       '
    End If
```